# Fetching data from firebase excluding ids

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app where I swipe profile and that is stored at another place in firebase. Like the id of the swiped profile. I don't want to see that profile again.
What I'm doing right now is getting profiles from the database and excluding all the swiped ids from that. It works fine when swiped profiles are not much. But when swiped profiles are more like 100. we fetch  75 from the database it excludes 75 profiles as those are already swiped. Then we make another fetch that excludes 25 more profiles and so on.
This makes loading for 3,4 minutes to just filtering. If there is any way we can make this filtration on the server-side. Instead of the app side.

Comment: Can you provide more information with some examples? i.e. screenshots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can query with not-in. So you have 'seen' profiles and 'all profiles'. Query 'all profiles' excluding 'seen'.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html

a relevant test
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/2b9c3212d3844d394f8d98f30cadc03fdef8c2f5/firestore/test.firestore.js#L891

Comment: thank you, This compound queries like "in"& "not-in" are supported just for 10 values. 
"Use the not-in operator to combine up to 10 not equal (!=) clauses on the same field with a logical AND."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries